# Contributing to Apache Kafka

Tags: debugging, testing, apache-kafka, open-source

I'm senior in Computer Science and I have to make contribution to Kafka project. After looking through the codebase and the issue tracker I found that the bug is quite difficult to fix as I have no idea where it would cause the bug.

So my next target is to understand the codebase more detail but because this is a big project so it is quite difficult to understand the flow. Anyone have any idea what should I do to contribute to the project?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This question is primarily opinion-based and is therefore _off-topic_.

Answer (score 0):

Contributing to open source projects can be a good way to improve your software engineering skill set.

Apache Kafka is a relatively big and complex piece of software with a large and very active community. It may appear daunting to get started but there's still plenty of approachable tasks for newcomers to get involved. I recommend to first read the [contributing guide](https://kafka.apache.org/contributing) on the Kafka website. It highlights the main processes and gives some guidance in finding something to do.

The project keeps a list of "starter" tasks in Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15752?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20newbie%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open. You don't have to pick one of these and feel free to tackle other open issues if you feel like it. I'd still recommend to start with something small before attempting larger changes.

If you have any questions, you can send them to the [developer mailing list](https://kafka.apache.org/contact).